Limit of expectation of ratio of sums of uniformly distributed variables
I saw this problem in past year exam of probability theory.
Let $U_1, \ldots, U_n, \ldots $ be independent standard uniformly distributed variables: $U_i \sim Uniform(0, 1)$ and $a>b>0$.
Calculate $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{U_1^a+\cdots+U_n^a}{U_1^b+\cdots+U_n^b}\right).$$
Intuitively, we can write it in the following way:
$\frac{U_1^a+\cdots+U_n^a}{n}$ by Central Limit Theorem goes to $N(\frac{1}{a+1}, \frac{1}{n})$, so goes to constant$\frac{1}{a+1}$. Similarly $\frac{U_1^b+\cdots+U_n^b}{n}$ goes to constant $\frac{1}{b+1}$. Therefore the ratio of two sums goes to ratio of two constants: $\frac{b+1}{a+1}$ as $n$ goes to infinity. So expectation is $\frac{b+1}{a+1}$. However, I am struggling to make this proof formal, how to deal with division by zero, etc.
How to write formally strict proof?

Are $a$ and $b$ power of $U_i$?

It is not CLT but SLLN's which you have to apply.

Yes, a and b are power.

By the strong law of large numbers,$\frac{U_1^a+\cdots+U_n^a}{U_1^b+\cdots+U_n^b}$ converges almost surely to $\frac{b+1}{a+1}$ as $n$ goes to infinity. Moreover it is positive and bounded by $1$ (because $a>b$). So by the dominated convergence theorem its expected value converges to $\frac{b+1}{a+1}$.
